# javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /pages/test.xhtml @12,74 value="#{Beans.IndexClient}"

Tags: jsf, el

how would I implement a function using JSF , I need to get the result of this function in a inputText.
Here is the code for the bean :

```
@ManagedBean(name="Beans") 
@ViewScoped
@Component 
public class Beans {

//----------- Recupérer le dernier index ---------//

    public Integer IndexClient;

    public Integer getIndexClient() {
        return lastIndexTache;
    }
    public void setIndexClient(Integer IndexTache) {
        this.IndexClient = IndexClient;
    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Session session =  HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        int index = 0;
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            String sql = "select MAX(t.idClient) from client t  ";
            Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
            if( query.uniqueResult()==null){

                index=0;
            }else{

                index=(int) query.uniqueResult();
                index=index+1;
            }
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        IndexClient = index;
    }
```

This is the view code :

```
<p:inputText value="#{Beans.IndexClient}" />
    </p:inputText>
```

The error:

```
`javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /pages/test.xhtml @12,74 value="#{Beans.IndexClient}": Method not found: com.bean.Beans@d802ee.IndexClient
```

I made several research on the internet but I have nothing and I'm stuck because of this mistake several days, if you have an idea please help me

Comment: Try `#{Beans.indexClient}`

Comment: already exists in code view

Comment: Change the variable name to 'indexClient' and in ui el try with `#{Beans.indexClient}`

Comment: like this <p:inputText value="#{ticketBean.indexClient}" /> ??? it's not work even with this modification

Comment: Don't forget to change this too:

`public Integer indexClient;

 public Integer getIndexClient() {
     return indexClient;
 }

 public void setIndexClient(Integer indexClient) {
     this.indexClient = indexClient;
 }`!

@user3850191 yes

Comment: @Smutje That didnt work :(